# MATLAB 3D plot using a defined function

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 3d

I have defined a function in a separate file which takes seven parameters and outputs one value. I want to create a 3D plot which will change with two of the parameters and I'm really stuck at how to do this.

So say my function is called using Ruth(a, b, c, d, e, f), and I want c-f to be fixed and plot the output value depending on values of a and b. Can anyone guide me on this? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Schorsch Thanks for your comment. I don't have any code to put down . There's no point in showing the function that I'm working with, as it's of no benefit. I just need help choosing a 3D plotting function. I know for a 2D plot I can use fplot(@Ruth,[10,200], [], [], [], b, c, d, e, f)...

Answer (score 0):

Use `meshgrid` to generate a grid of points over the range of a and b that you are interested in.  Then evaluate your function at each of those (a,b) point pairs, forming a 2D matrix.  Then use `mesh` or `surf` to plot your matrix against the a,b independent variables.  Here's an example, with a really simple function:

```
function out = myfunc(a,b,c)
out = c + a.*b;

[a,b] = meshgrid(-50:50, -50:50);
c = 10;
z = myfunc(a, b, c);
mesh(a, b, z);
```

Note that in my case, I've written my function to be "vectorized", meaning it will accept vectors or arrays of inputs and operate on the entire array.  If yours is not, you'll have to evaluate your function with a nested loop over a and b, something like this:

```
z = zeros(size(a));
for ii=1:size(a,1)
    for jj=1:size(a,2)
        z(ii,jj) = Ruth(a(ii,jj), b(ii,jj), c, d, e, f);
    end
end
```